# Access value of formControl from formArray in reactive form in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

How do I access value of ItemName in HTML. It says undefined when I try `{{invoiceForm.controls[i].items.controls.itemName.value | json}}` in below code.

```
<form [formGroup]="invoiceForm">

<div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i=index;">

  <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <input type="text" formControlName="itemName">
      <input type="number" formControlName="itemQty">       
      <input type="number" formControlName="itemPrice">
  </div>  

  Item name:  {{invoiceForm.controls[i].items.controls.itemName.value | json}}

</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there...

instead of:

```
{{invoiceForm.controls[i].items.controls.itemName.value | json}}
```

You should write:

```
{{invoiceForm.controls['items'].controls[i].controls.itemName.value | json}}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8i9sca) example

---

In order to tell the exact path to go, you could have just print the form value with `console.log(this.invoiceForm)` on `ngOnInit` and then you could have seen that the `'item'` is a direct key of `'controls'`, your only mistake was to refer `invoiceForm.controls[0]` which is wrong.

Here is a little extra for achieving the same outcome form ts file (hard coded to the first item):

```
console.log(this.invoiceForm);
const itemControls = <FormArray>this.invoiceForm.controls['items'];
const itemFormGroup = <FormGroup>itemControls.controls[0];
console.log(itemFormGroup.controls["itemName"].value);
```

Comment: Its showing value but in visual editor it shows it as error.

Comment: Identifier 'controls' is not defined. 'AbstractControl' does not contain such a member.
This as error.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kzkxwu
I tried here same, but getting this error. Can you check what's missing

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: {{invoiceForm.controls['items'].controls[i].controls.itemName.value | json}}
I've tried this with my form but it throws error :  Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.    https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kzkxwu

Comment: It is because you will need to print the `{{invoiceForm....}}` inside the div with the `ngFor`, otherwise you won't have access to `i`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kzkxwu  It is inside div, but it look like its issue of using controls.

Comment: Identifier 'controls' is not defined. 'AbstractControl' does not contain such a member.

Comment: Hey @AbhijeetRaj, not sure where you are getting this error message maybe on your local, check this out: https://angular-8i9sca.stackblitz.io/ it is free of errors

Answer (score 1):

instead of
`{{invoiceForm.controls[i].items.controls.itemName.value | json}}`

Try this in html :

```
{{getFormControlItem()[i].controls['dateofStay'].value}}
```

Component ts code :

```
getFormControlItem()
{
return ((this.invoiceForm.controls['items'] as FormArray).controls as FormGroup[])
}
```

this will not throw this error : Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

This workerd in my case .

Comment: use get: `{{invoiceForm.get('items.'+i+'.itemName')?.value}}` or `{{invoiceForm.value?.items[i].itemName}}`. The "safe operator" (the `?` before the `.`) say to Angular that if the element is null not show nothing.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).